# How to make button blinking infinite, but with possibility to stop at anytime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, effects, jquery-ui-button

I need to make button to start blinking after some other elemment trigered it, for example checking the checkbox - see the code below:

```
<label>I agree with the terms</label>
<input class="some_check" type="checkbox" id="Signed">
<button class="buttonstyle" name="buttonNext" onClick="nextChoose('NEXT')" disabled>Proceed!</button>
```

Blinking must be infinite until:

1. user clicks the button or
2. unchecks the checkbox.

I know there's `.effect()` method in jQuery UI, but it's time-limited
and if I loop it through the callback, how than I can break it to return button in a previous state?

Comment: There's a reason the blink tag died...

Comment: u mean all those effets look disgusting? take a look here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/, i think they'r quite intelegent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe your looking for something like this [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zKWxp/1/)

CSS:

```
#click, #btn {margin: 20px;}
```

JavaScript:

```
var timer;

$("#blink").on('change', function() {
    if ($("#blink").is(':checked')) {
        blinking($("#btn"));
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
});

$("#btn").click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    $("#blink").attr('checked', false);
});



function blinking(elm) {
    timer = setInterval(blink, 10);
    function blink() {
        elm.fadeOut(400, function() {
           elm.fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="blink"/>
<input type="button" value="CLICK ME" id="btn" />
```

Comment: @shershen I know it might be too late to ask this, but I am stuck here.. I am using this solution and after some time I get error of "Out of stack memory".. Did you face this issue?.. If yes what solution you used?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` to make something happen over and over again, and later call `clearInterval` on its return value to make it stop. [Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/CHgLM/1/) to get you started.

Comment: maybe i was no correct in my explanation, but the button must start blinking AFTER i check checkbox - it's even not the main point, but it's important, than AFTER UNCHECK the button must return to previous state